# Vertices of a Polyhedron

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, convex-analysis, polyhedra

I ask your expertise for the following point:

let P be a polyhedron unbounded and without lines. According to a standard decomposition, P can be written as:

$$P= M + K$$

(+ stands for the Minkowsky sum)

where $M$ is the polytope spanned by its vertices and $K$ is the recession cone of $P$.

**My questions is:**

Let F be proper face of P

$$F = P \cap H,$$
defined by the plane
$$H = \{x\in V : \ell (x) = \alpha\}.$$  If $p$ is a point of $F$, can I say that

$$p = m + u,$$

where

$$m \in M\cap F, \quad u \in H$$

If the sentence is correct, what is the proof the claim?

Thank you very much in advance for your reply

Comment: You want to enclose each mathematical sentence or formula between dollar signs, to get the right effect.

Comment: Hi Lubin, thanks for your hint. I will follow it